# How to make layer effects following transformations

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, resize

I'm creating a shape with a simple radial glow effect.

Now I want to add some perspective, with Cmd-T, then right clic and "perspective".

When I'm done, all layer effects are recalculated and my radial effect has no more perspective. Any other solution than pixelise the layer ?

What i want :

[image: What I want]

What I get :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert the layer to a Smart Object *or* a bitmap layer, the transformation will be applied to the entire thing. Please note that converting to a Smart Object will effectively change the layer to a bitmap.

To convert to a Smart Object, right click or command-click the layer in the layers panel and choose `Convert to Smart Object`.

To convert to a bitmap layer, right click or command-click the layer in the layers panel and choose `Rasterize Layer`.

Comment: Okay, I didn't know what exactly where smart objects, it seems to be useful!